# Array2D and jagged arrays in f#

Tags: arrays, f#, jagged-arrays

I wrote this f# code to create a jagged (non-rectangular) array.

```
open System

type MatrizIrregular() = 
  let irregular = Array2D.zeroCreate 5

  member This.Inicializar() =
    for f in 0 .. 4 do
      printf "Introduzcal el número de columnas de la matriz de la fila %d: " f
      let res = Console.ReadLine()
      let col = Int32.Parse(res)
      Array2D.set irregular f (col)
      for c in 0 .. col - 1 do
        printf "Introduzca el valor de la columna %d: " c
        let res2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Array2D.set irregular f c (Int32.Parse(res2))

  member This.Mostrar() = 
    for f in 0 .. 4 do
    for f in 0 .. irregular.[f,c].Lenght - 1 do
      printf "%d " irregular.[f,c]
      printf "\n" 

let matriz = MatrizIrregular()
matriz.Inicializar()
matriz.Mostrar()
```

I get errors on lines 11,15

> This expression was expected to have type 'a[,] but here has type int -> 'b[,]

and on lines 19,20

> The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding futher type constrains.

I want do something like this java code in f#

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MatrizIrregular {
    public Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
public int[][] irregular;

public void inicializar(){
    irregular = new int[5][];
    for(int f=0;f<irregular.length;f++){
            System.out.print("Introduzca el numero de columnas del la fila de la matriz "+f+": ");
    int col = teclado.nextInt();
    irregular[f] = new int[col];
    for(int c =0; c<irregular[f].length;c++){
        System.out.print("Introduzca el elemento de la columna "+c+": ");
            irregular[f][c] = teclado.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

public void mostrar(){
    for(int f=0;f<irregular.length;f++){
            for(int c=0;c<irregular[f].length;c++){
               System.out.print(irregular[f][c]+" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
}

public static void main(String[] ar){
     MatrizIrregular matriz = new MatrizIrregular();
     matriz.inicializar();
     matriz.mostrar();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 2D array is not irregular, so similar to java you need to declare an `array` of an `array` of `int`s. In F# that's `int array array` and zeroCreate needs to know what type it's going to initialize an array for. Also be careful of indentation, your nested for loops weren't indented properly.

```
open System

type MatrizIrregular() = 
  let irregular : int array array = Array.zeroCreate 5

  member This.Inicializar() =
    for f in 0 .. 4 do
      printf "Introduzcal el número de columnas de la matriz de la fila %d: " f
      let res = Console.ReadLine()
      let col = Int32.Parse(res)
      let cols : int array = Array.zeroCreate col
      for c in 0 .. col - 1 do
        printf "Introduzca el valor de la columna %d: " c
        let res2 = Console.ReadLine()
        Array.set cols c (Int32.Parse(res2))
      Array.set irregular f cols

  member This.Mostrar() = 
    for f in 0 .. 4 do
      for c in 0 .. (Array.length irregular.[f]) - 1 do
        printf "%d " irregular.[f].[c]
      printf "\n" 

let matriz = MatrizIrregular()
matriz.Inicializar()
matriz.Mostrar()
```

Not the most functional answer, but it is what was asked for.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make jagged 2D arrays like this. `Array2D` and the type `[,]` and can only be used for rectangular 2D arrays.

To see how to work with jagged arrays, take a look at [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Arrays#Jagged_arrays).

---

I'd like to comment on your use of `Array2D.zeroCreate`. It has this type:

```
val it : (int -> int -> 'a [,])
```

When you have given it two integers, it'll give you an array. If you give it only one integer:

```
let irregular = Array2D.zeroCreate 5
val irregular : (int -> '_a [,])     (* Also complains about generic types. *)
```

You get a function that when given the missing second dimension will give you an array. You don't get an array with an unspecified second dimension.

(Maybe try and play with `let f x y = x + y` and `f 1` in the interpreter; see what the types are and try to apply `f` to one or two things.)